# Find the basis for the null space of the linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

The question is

> $P_2$: the vector space of 2nd order polynomial. The linear transformation $T$ is defined as $T: P_2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $T(p(x)) = p(2)$. Find the basis of $N(T)$.

The answer is $\left\{x^2-4, x-2\right\}$.

**My approach:**
$$N(T):=\left\{ p(x)\middle| T(p(x))=0 \right\}$$
=> $p(2) = 0$
$$\forall \alpha,\beta,\gamma \in \mathbb{R}, p(x) = \alpha x^2+\beta x + \gamma$$
$$P(2)=4\alpha +2\beta + \gamma$$

I got stuck here and wasn't able to proceed. The only hint I have on this question is the answer itself. And I also understand that the answer is correct. But I can't find a logical way of finding  $x^2-4$ and $x-2$ as the basis of $N(T)$. I guess that guessing can be an approach but guessing won't work on all problems so I want a more rigid solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$N(T)$ consists of polynomials $a+bx+cx^{2}$ such that $a+2b+4c=0$. This gives $a==-2b-4c$ so the polynomial becomes $p(x)=-2b-4c+bx+cx^{2}=b(x-2)+c(x^{2}-4)$ with $b$ and $c$ arbitrary. So $N(t)$ is spanned by $x^{2}-4$ and $x-2$. I will let you check  that these two polynomials are linearly independent which implies that they form a basis for $N(T)$.